# Python selenium webdriver element not found

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on one of web automation project and i get stuck on one button
my python program not able to find element for that filter button

html code for that button is

```
<a role="button" class="list_filter_toggle icon-filter btn btn-icon" tabindex="0" 
title="" id="task_filter_toggle_image" 
aria-controls="taskfilterdiv" 
aria-expanded="false" data-original-title="Show / hide filter"><span 
class="sr-only">Show / hide filter</span></a>
```

and my code is

```
btn=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Show / hide filter'")
btn.click()
```

error message

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an 
element with the xpath expression //*[contains(text(), 'Show / hide filter' because of the following 
error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(text(), 'Show / 
hide filter'' is not a valid XPath expression.
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
```

please help me , i need to click on button but not able to find button element

Comment: what happens if you use:  find_element_by_id("task_filter_toggle_image")

Comment: You're missing the closing parentheses for `(text`.  And also the closing square bracket for `[contains`.

Comment: Try `find_elements_by_class_name()` method

Comment: What's wrong with using the ID to find the A tag?

Comment: with  find_element_by_id("task_filter_toggle_image")  getting error    -------------- raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="task_filter_toggle_image"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
website = "www.stackoverflow.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(website)

e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Show / hide filter']")

print(e)
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
    Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='Show / hide filter']"}
    (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)
     Stacktrace:  ------------ No luck still giving error

Comment: @DineshSharma i have tested exactly what u have provided in html as you forementioned and had a result.  read the error, it says unable to locate elements. it's not a bug.